# Animation in java

Tags: java, user-interface, animation

I need to make a face that smiles when the program starts but the smile on the animation doesn't move unless you extend the window when its running, right now then it shows up as a full circle for some reason[My work so far vs task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKvds.jpg) .

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FaceAnimation extends JFrame {
private StillClock face = new StillClock();

public FaceAnimation() {
add(face);


}
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
@Override /** Handle the action event */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new FaceAnimation();
frame.setTitle("FaceAnimation");
frame.setSize(400, 400);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

class StillClock extends JPanel {
private int mouthOpening;





@Override /** Draw the face */
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
super.paintComponent(g);

// Initialize face parameters

int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
int radius = (int)(Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight())* 0.4);

int x = xCenter - radius;
int y = yCenter - radius;


g.setColor (Color.BLACK);
g.drawOval(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

g.setColor (Color.BLACK);
g.fillOval (xCenter - radius * 3/5, yCenter - radius* 2/5, 20, 20);

g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.fillOval(xCenter + radius * 2/5, yCenter - radius*2/5, 20, 20);

g.setColor(Color.RED);
mouthOpening = mouthOpening + 10;
g.drawArc(xCenter - 3*radius/5, yCenter - radius/2, 6*radius/5,      radius*6/5, 270-mouthOpening/2, mouthOpening);

 }
 @Override
 public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  return new Dimension(800, 800);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FaceAnimation extends JFrame {
    private StillClock face = new StillClock();

    public FaceAnimation() {
        add(face);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new FaceAnimation();
        frame.setTitle("FaceAnimation");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class StillClock extends JPanel {

    private int mouthOpening;
    private Timer timer;

    public StillClock() {
        timer = new Timer(25, new TimerListener());
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
        int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
        int radius = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

        int x = xCenter - radius;
        int y = yCenter - radius;

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(xCenter - radius * 3 / 5, yCenter - radius * 2 / 5, 20, 20);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(xCenter + radius * 2 / 5, yCenter - radius * 2 / 5, 20, 20);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawArc(xCenter - 3 * radius / 5, yCenter - radius / 2, 6 * radius / 5, radius * 6 / 5, 270 - mouthOpening / 2, mouthOpening);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 800);
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (mouthOpening > 180) {
            mouthOpening = 0;
        } else {
            mouthOpening = mouthOpening + 10;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code was, that `paintComponent` isn't called in a loop. The Method is only called when the dialog is drawn for the first time and on certain events like resizing. You can also do it manually with the method `repaint()` which will call `paintComponent`.

The following example uses a Timer that will update you dialog periodically using `updateMouth` Method and an instance of MouthUpdateTime.
`updateMouth` simply updates your `mouthOpening` value and the UI using `repaint`.

The timer is created with an instance of `MouthUpdateTimer`. The timer calls `actionPerformed` of the given instance every `UPDATE_INTERVALL` ms (here 50ms) which then uses the `updateMouth` to animate your mouth.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FaceAnimation extends JFrame {

  private StillClock face = new StillClock();

   public FaceAnimation() {
      add(face);
   }

private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    /** Handle the action event */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new FaceAnimation();
    frame.setTitle("FaceAnimation");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}


class StillClock extends JPanel {

private int mouthOpening = 30; // start with 30°
private int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 50; //wait 50 ms between each update

public StillClock() {
    new Timer(UPDATE_INTERVAL, new MouthUpdateTimer()).start();

}

@Override
/** Draw the face */
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Initialize face parameters
    int xCenter = getWidth() / 2;
    int yCenter = getHeight() / 2;
    int radius = (int) (Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 0.4);

    int x = xCenter - radius;
    int y = yCenter - radius;


    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawOval(x, y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(xCenter - radius * 3 / 5, yCenter - radius * 2 / 5, 20, 20);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(xCenter + radius * 2 / 5, yCenter - radius * 2 / 5, 20, 20);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);

    g.drawArc(xCenter - 3 * radius / 5, yCenter - radius / 2, 6 * radius / 5, radius * 6 / 5,
            270 - mouthOpening / 2, mouthOpening);
}

/**
 * Updates mouthOpening and updates the UI.
 */
private void updateMouth(){
    if(mouthOpening > 180){ // redraw after 180°
        mouthOpening = 30;
    } else {
        mouthOpening = mouthOpening + 1;
    }
    repaint(); // redraw the dialog
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(800, 800);
}

private class MouthUpdateTimer implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            updateMouth(); // calls updateMouth 
    }
}
}
```